# Write a regex to get numbers between two delimiters

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, delimiter

I need to parse a string and get the numbers between 2 delimiters. I need to be sure they're numbers. I tried something like this but doesn't work as expected.

```
if (preg_match_all("/[^0-9](?<=First)(.*?)(?=Second)/s", $haystack, $result))
for ($i = 1; count($result) > $i; $i++) {
    print_r($result[$i]);
}
```

What's wrong with the regex?

Comment: What is the input, what do you expect and what do you get?

Comment: Jesus, that depends.  What's in `$haystack`?  What comes out in `$result`?  What would you like to come out in `$result`?

Comment: How did you come up with `[^0-9]` at the start, why are you using lookarounds, and not just the literal delimiters and a number match in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, that's almost the one I supplied to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18194080/1578604) xD

Change the `(.*?)` to `([0-9]+)`

```
if (preg_match_all("/(?<=First)([0-9]+)(?=Second)/s", $haystack, $result))
for ($i = 1; count($result) > $i; $i++) {
    print_r($result[$i]);
}
```

`.*?` will match any character (except newlines) and to match only numbers in between your delimiters "First" and "Second", you will need to change it to `[0-9]`. Then, I assume that there can't be nothing in between them, so we use a `+` instead of a `*`.

I'm not sure why you used `[^0-9]` in the beginning. Usually `[^0-9]` means one character which is not a number, and putting it there doesn't really do something useful, at least in my opinion.

---

Cleaning up a little, you could remove a few things that aren't needed to get the required output:

```
if (preg_match_all("/(?<=First)[0-9]+(?=Second)/", $haystack, $result))
   print_r($result[0]);
```

Comment: @Martijn I just saw your suggested edit and you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/1578604) to see why I used `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless here because there are no `.` in the pattern.  The capture group is useless here because the captured substring is identical to the fullstring match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[0-9]` or `\d` to ensure that the characters between the delimiters are numbers. using this you also won't need the lazy quantifier (unless your delimiters are actually numbers, too):

```
preg_match_all("/[^0-9](?<=First)(\d*)(?=Second)/s", $haystack, $result)
```

Or

```
preg_match_all("/[^0-9](?<=First)([0-9]*)(?=Second)/s", $haystack, $result)
```

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier is useless here because there are no `.` in the pattern.  The capture group is useless here because the captured substring is identical to the fullstring match.